# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in route param

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

Following along in a [ExpressJS course on TUTS+](https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/getting-started-with-express)

I have the following ([exact from video](https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/getting-started-with-express/lessons/custom-middleware-based-on-route-parameters)):

```
var express = require('express'),
app     = express();

app.get('/name/:name', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Your name is ' + res.params.name);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

However if I go to `http://localhost:3000/name/` error: **Cannot GET /name/**

If I goto `http://localhost:3000/name/Leon`

error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
   at /Users/leongaban/Projects/Node/expressApp/server3.js:5:39
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/leongaban/Projects/Node/expressApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
   at next (/Users/leongaban/Projects/Node/expressApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:100:13)
   at Route.dispatch (/Users/leongaban/Projects/Node/expressApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:81:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/leongaban/Projects/Node/expressApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
   at /Users/leongaban/Projects/Node/expressApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:235:24
   at param (/Users/leongaban/Projects/Node/expressApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:332:14)
   at param (/Users/leongaban/Projects/Node/expressApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:348:14)
   at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/leongaban/Projects/Node/expressApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:392:3)
   at /Users/leongaban/Projects/Node/expressApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:229:12
```

Not sure what I'm missing?

Comment: if you are using `body-parser` you will get it in `req.query.name`.

Comment: `body-parser` does not parse the url parameters, only the body of the request. The parsed body appears in `req.body`. `req.query` contains the key-value pairs from the query string, after the `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `params` are on the `req`. Use `req.params.name`.

Regarding the **Cannot GET /name/**, if you specify a parameter in the route leaving that portion of the url empty will not match your route. You have to populate the `:name` portion of the url to hit the route.

Answer (score 1):

Request object contains parameters not response. Thought of the request you make to ther server with request paarameters in it? so Request object holds them

you need `req.params.name`